# Keras configuration file under virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, keras

I'm using Python distributed through anaconda. I have several virtual environment settings created through conda. Now my question is, if I have different Keras versions installed for the virtual environments, are they going to use the same Keras configuration file at `~/.keras/keras.json`?

If not, where are the configuration files located?

Comment: An experiment: Activate a virtual environment, modify `~/.keras/keras.json` and see if the change has an effect. If so, you'll know that's the config file that the virtual environment is using. (But first copy or back up the `keras.json` file to a safe place, so you can restore it afterwards if necessary!)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a following code fragment](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/6f3e6bb6fc97e706f37dc078ae821f490b78035b/keras/backend/__init__.py#L1-L24) in Keras repo which I believe means that this path is hardcoded to live inside of `~/.keras/keras.json`